# Create groups for INSERT based on IDs of source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to regroup some Ids, and create unique ID in a grouping table (acting as a bridge table in my data warehouse).

I got in a the source table transactionId, UserId and OrganisationId.
What I want to do is to create "groups" of OrganisationId, depending on User association, in order to use this group in a joint.

See below:

Original datas

```
  TransaID   UserId   OrgaId  
 ---------- -------- -------- 
  24011035        1      180  
  24011035        1       19  
  24011040        2       89  
  24011064        3       89  
  24011070        4       19  
  24011082        4      180  
  24011106        5       89  
  24011106        5      180  
  24011107        6      180
```

Desired output

```
  OrgaGroupId   OrgaId  
 ------------- -------- 
            1      180  
            1       19  
            2       89  
            3      180  
            3       89  
            4      180
```

I've created 1 group for combination of Orga 180 and 19, as 2 users got it.
Two simple groups for OrgaId 89 and 180, as they appear only once associated to a user.
And finally, another group for 180 and 89, as it's a new combination.

What would be the T-SQL statements to achieve output exposed above?

Comment: What have *you* tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(TransaID int, UserId int, OrgaId int);

insert into @t(TransaID, UserId, OrgaId)
values
(24011035, 1, 180), 
(24011035, 1, 19), 
(24011040, 2, 89), 
(24011064, 3, 89), 
(24011070, 4, 19), 
(24011082, 4, 180), 
(24011106, 5, 89), 
(24011106, 5, 180), 
(24011107, 6, 180); 


select /*straggr,*/ OrgaId, dense_rank() over(order by min(UserId)) as grpid
from
(
select a.*, 
(select distinct concat(b.OrgaId, ',') from @t as b where b.UserId = a.UserId order by concat(b.OrgaId, ',') for xml path('')) as straggr
from @t as a
) as t
group by straggr, OrgaId;
```

Comment: Thank you but doen't work, I got a lot of dupplicate for my groups of Organisations.

Comment: ..@DamienB could you add sample data that result in duplicates? edited the answer for distinct OrgaIds...